# Error using imagesc on Matlab, namely: "Numeric or logical matrix required for image CDate"

Tags: matlab, plot

I wanted to use `imagesc` on a function loop I created which has output of the form

```
0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0003 + 0.0001i   0.0000 - 0.0000i
0.0002 - 0.0003i   0.0003 + 0.0001i   0.0000 - 0.0000i
0.0002 - 0.0002i   0.0003 + 0.0001i  -0.0001 + 0.0003i
0.0002 - 0.0002i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i   0.0000 - 0.0000i
-0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i   0.0000 - 0.0000i
-0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
-0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
-0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
-0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 - 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
-0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 - 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
-0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 - 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
-0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 - 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
-0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 - 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
```

(well, a lot more data than that, but just to give you a small taste).

The loop is of the form

```
Fn = zeros(length(omega),length(theta));
for k = 1:length(omega)
    for l = 1:length(theta)
        Fn(k,l) = ....
    end
 end
```

where `...` is some `integral2` expression applied to an anonymous function.

Can anyone identify what the problem might be? In particular, I get the error message: `Error using image Numeric or logical matrix required for image CDate`

Comment: Yes, the problem is you have complex numbers and an image cannot contain complex numbers, even in the `CData`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just see the imaginary part as

```
imagesc(imag(Fn));
```